# How do you find the Ubuntu Software Center in the File System

Tags: 13.04, software-center, flash

I'm trying to download a apt file of Adobe Flash Plater for other browsers but I can't seem to find the Software Center. There is no application already checked off for downloading it. Does anyone know where it is?

Comment: If the file is a `.deb` file, the Software Center is associated with it. After downloading, right click it and there should be an option to open it with SC. (Software Center is at `/usr/bin/software-center`, kinda). If the file is `.bin` then it is meant to be run on the terminal. If you gave us more details we could be able to help you better, though.

Comment: thanks buddy this is working among many non working tips

Comment: I think the issue is that apt files, that is links that should open in the Ubuntu software center are not associated with it. For example the link on this page: [ubunbtu-restricted-extras](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras/) opens the launch application window, but there is no software center to select. Atleast that's the issue i'm having, if it's a different issue I can open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you may open up a terminal ctrl-alt-t and type: $ software-center and just type flash in the search box and see if its not ready installed...also have you installed ubuntu-restricted-extras?

Hope this helps,

Luis